# Tips on making a video uploader secure?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

So, I cannot seem to find any decent PHP Video Uploaders that use FFMPEG so I've decided to attempt to create my own.

Video uploading is more scarier than images because images has many more tools offered by PHP to validate it's legitimacy. But how do we validate legitimacy with videos? Is there any tips that could help me? Much appreciated!

Also, if you know any Video converters that are useful, could help me further :)

Comment: One suggestion is to make sure you're using a recent `ffmpeg` build to ensure you're not vulnerable to an already fixed issue that may have security implications.

Comment: I am already using the latest version of FFMPEG, my biggest concern is people uploading malicious files such as like a c99 shell and having it disguised. Like sure the video goes through a conversion but the file still goes to a temp directory where the raw file is till it's done converting.